# Automate Lead Conversion in Salesforce

Tags: visual-workflow, process-builder, lead-conversion, automation

In salesforce, lead is converted into Account, Contact, and Opportunity. Opportunity is optional to create upon conversion.

The convert button on Lead does the conversion. Is it possible to convert the lead through standard automation like process builder or flow?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, yes you can do this in Flow (or Process Builder) but you will need to invoke an Apex invocable class to do the actual lead conversion using the [Database.convertLead method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_examples_convertlead.htm)

The [Salesforce Automation Champion blog post](https://automationchampion.com/tag/auto-convert-lead-using-process-builder/) describes this in detail. [UnofficialSF.com (managed by the Flow Product Manager) has very specific details](https://unofficialsf.com/understanding-invocable-actions/) on what the invocable method should look like.

- Flow or Process Builder triggered by DML event
- Calls invocable Apex; you pass to the Apex method the parameters needed for the conversion (which account, whether to create an Opportunity, etc.)